# Clarification about correct steps to follow for second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve this Cauchy's Problem:

$$\begin{cases}y''-y'+3y=x^2-x+3\\y(0)=y'(0)=0 \end{cases}$$

But I have a doubt about the correct steps to follow.

It was told me that a second-order ODE is solved by $y=y_o+z$ where $y_o$ is the solution of the homogeneous equation and $z$ is a particular solution of the equation.

But it was also told me that, given $y''+ay'+by=f$, $z$ is obtained by:
$$z=-y_1 \int f \frac{y_2}{W} dx+y_2 \int f \frac{y_1}{W}dx$$
where $y_1, y_2$ are solutions of the homogeneous equation and $W$ is the Wronskian.

I don't understand why in the solutions book, it is written:
$$z=A+Bx+Cx^2$$ Then it proceedes finding $A$, $B$, $C$ in the following way:

$$z'=B+2Cx$$
$$z''=2C$$

$$(2C)-(B+2Cx)+3(A+Bx+Cx^2)=x^2-x+3$$

And I understand it, but I don't understand why $z=A+Bx+Cx^2$... Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you find the particular solution of $$y'' - y' + 3y = x^2 - x + 3$$ by the method of undetermined coefficients. that is look for solutions in the form $$y = ax^2 + bx + c, \quad y' = 2ax + b, \quad y'' = 2a. $$ sub everything back $$2a-(2ax+b) + 3(ax^2 + bx + c) = x^2 - x + 1 \\
\to a = \frac 13, 3b - 2a = -1, b = -\frac 19,\\
 2a-b+3c = 1\to  c = \frac2{27}$$

that is, if everything is alright,  $$y_p= \frac13x^2-\frac19x+\frac2{27}  $$ is a particular solution. it is unlikely to satisfy the initial condition. so we go an look for the solution to the hgs problem $$y'' - y' + 3y =0 $$ in the form $y = e^{kx}.$  the $k$ needs to satisfy the char equation $$k^2 -k + 3= 0 \to k = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{11}i}2 $$  the hgs solution is $$y_h = e^{x/2}\left(a\cos\sqrt{11}x + b\sin\sqrt{11}x\right)  $$

the general solution is $$y=y_h + y_g.$$  i will let you detrmine the constants $a, b$ so that $y$ satisfies the initial conditions $y(0) = 0 = y'(0)$

Comment: I'm sorry, Abel. I haven't understood why the particular solution is in the form $y = ax^2 + bx + c $..

Comment: That happens because the right side $f$ is a solution of $f'''(x)=0$. In every case where the right side satisfies a linear ODE with constant coefficients, the approach with a trial solution works.

Comment: @sunrise, let $Ly = y'' - y' + 3y.$  can you compute $L(x62), L(x), L(1)?$

Comment: I have understood: the problem is that I don't know the method of undetermined coefficients. I only know the variation of constants method. I have searched something on the net, but I have only found the rules to follow, but not the reason why I can use them... In particular, I haven't understood why $y''+ay'+by=f$ admit, as particular solution, $z=ax^2+bx+c$... To establish this rule, have they guessed and found that this relation is always valid? Are there any other reasons?

Comment: @LutzL I'm sorry, I haven't understood what you mean..

Comment: @sunrise, it is trial and error. it also depends on the forcing, i.e, the expression on the right hand side. for example, in your equation, an $x^2$ on the right hand side you expect the response to be in the form $ax^2 + bx + c.$  if it were $e^{5x},$  you would try a response of $ae^{5x}, etc$

Comment: Thanks, Abel! It's clear now!

Comment: No, it is not trial-and-error, there are very specific circumstances that allow for the method of undetermined coefficients to work, and then it will definitely work. In all other cases, only variation of coefficients is applicable and in many cases will end up with integrals that can not be simplified to a closed form.

Answer (score 0):

The rule for undetermined coefficients is rather simple, if the assumptions for it are satisfied. First, the linear differential equation $L(y)=f$ *needs to have* constant coefficients.

Then, the right hand side or inhomogeneity $f$ *needs to be* a sum of terms where each term is a product of a polynomial and an exponential. The case polynomial times exponential times sine or cosine falls also under this pattern, since $\cos(w·x)=(e^{iwx}+e^{-iwx})/2$ etc.

For each of the term one may compute a trial solution separately and add all of them up in the end to get the particular solution.

For each term $p(x)·e^{\lambda x}$ one uses the trial function $y=x^m·q(x)·e^{λx}$ where $m$ is the multiplicity of $λ$ as root of the characteristic polynomial of $L$ and $\deg q=\deg p$. The coefficients of $q$ are the unknown parameters that have to be computed from $$L(x^m·q(x)·e^{λx})=p(x)·e^{λx}.$$