# When is a test function multiplied by "$t$" for inhomogeneous ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was wondering how we can tell that we need to multiply our arbitrary function by $t$ when we're solving an inhomogeneous ODE?

For example, I had the following equation to solve$$\ddot x(t) +x(t) = 4\cos(t) + \cos(2t).$$The solution showed that I needed to multiply the test function associated with $4\cos(t)$ by $t$. That is, if the particular solution is defined as $$x_p(t) = x_p^{(1)}(t) + x_p^{(2)}(t)$$then I had that $$x_p^{(1)}(t) = t(c_1\cdot \cos(t) + c_2\cdot \sin(t))$$and $$x_p^{(2)}(t) = c_3\cdot \cos(2t) + c_4\cdot \sin(2t).$$Is it because the $\cos(t)$ term is multiplied by a constant? So it could be the result of the chain rule [e.g. $\frac{d}{dt}(4t\cos(t))$]?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Method of Undetermined Coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using the undetermined coefficient, so since $\ddot{x}+x=4\cos(t)$ so you suppose the particular solution is given by $x_{p}^{(1)}=t^{s}(A\cos t+B\sin t)$ for some $s$ what you need to find. In this case $s=1$ work. Similar case for $\ddot{x}+x=\cos 2t$ so you suppose the particular solution is given by $x_{p}^{(2)}=t^{s}(C\cos 2t+D\sin 2t)$ for some $s$ which you need to find. In this case $s=0$ work.

The method of undetermined coefficients is an educated guess or an educated intuition of the form that a particular solution will take. There are many forms or rules already established for cases like the one I just mentioned.

In your case the complementary solution is given by
$$x_{c}=c_{1}\cos t+c_{2}\sin t$$ with $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ arbitrary constants.

And the particular solution is given by
$$x_{p}=-\frac{1}{3}\cos 2t+2t\sin t$$
by superposition principle.

Therefore the general solution for the ODE is given by
$$x=x_{c}+x_{p}$$
Is to say,
$$\boxed{x=c_{1}\cos t+c_{2}\sin t-\frac{1}{3}\cos 2t+2t\sin t}$$

There is also the parameter variation method that has closed formulas to find the particular solution. If you need more detail, I can add more information in my post.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering how I can determine the degree $s$ of $t$. Do I substitute my guess in the ODE and choose $s$ such that the (lowest) degree of the polynomial on the LHS is equal to the degree of the polynomial on the RHS? For example, substituting $x_p^{(1)}$ in the ODE $\ddot x(t) + x(t) = 4\cos(t)$ yields $$s(s-1)t^{s-2}(A\cos(t)+B\sin(t)) + 2st^{s-1}(-A\sin(t)+B\cos(t)) = 4\cos(t).$$Do I choose $s=1$ so that the $t^{s-1}$ is equal to $t^0$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant highest not lowest

Comment: The idea is a bit finer: you choose s to be the smallest positive integer such that the particular solution does not already make a solution of the complementary solution appear. Let me explain this a bit more and see if we take $s=1$ at $x_{p}^{(1)}$, then we just get the complementary solution and that's it; so now we see in $s=1$ and if it doesn't work we continue in the same direction (here $s=1$ work). Is it more clear?

Comment: Each choice of $s$ that we make must take care that for that value the solution has not already been considered. Note that for $x_{p}^{(2)}$ taking $s=0$ works because this solution has not appeared.

Comment: It is not "educated guessing", there are very strict rules when and how this can be applied. I once wrote a summary in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254118/clarification-about-correct-steps-to-follow-for-second-order-ode/1254430#1254430

Comment: @user1027216 I think I get it. So the "criterion" for choosing $s$ is such that the particular solution isn't in the same form as the complementary solution? which I guess makes sense since, for example choosing $s=0$ for $x_p^{(1)}$, the LHS would just be equal to zero..

Comment: @LutzLehmann Hello, thanks for the comment is always appreciated. I don't mean to contradict your comment, in fact I agree that there are strict rules for assumptions. However, many texts state that this is an "educated guess" for example here https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.uah.edu/images/people/faculty/howellkb/DEText-Ch21.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiXkP_bnNr3AhWaSjABHV-DBnYQFnoECGIQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1H3G1mSPi0-0kukXIkXa8T. So pedagogically (which is my main concern) I think it is useful to teach that this method consists of an initial assumption that is the basis here.

Comment: Here https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/undeterminedcoefficients.aspx also the Paul Dawkins professor also refers to this. Among other texts that I have had the opportunity to read. If we go to the rigorous study of differential equations, of course I agree with what you say @LutzLehmann

Comment: @Lea Yes if $s=0$ in $x_{p}^{(1)}$ so we get $x_{p}^{(1)}=A\cos t+B\sin t$ but we already had that solution which was the complementary solution, so now we try with $s=1$ which does work here because $x_{p}^{(1)}=t(A\cos t+B\sin t)$ has not appeared yet. I also added a link of the professor Paul Dawkins where he has a chart you can read.

Comment: Strictly $s$ is the number of times $0$ is a root of the characteristic equation, $\alpha$ is a root of the characteristic equation, and $\alpha+i\beta$ is a root of the characteristic equation, respectively.@Lea

Comment: @user1027216 Thank you so much!

Comment: It's a pleasure to help, many successes!